# Will dynamic allocations on a different thread slow down my main processing thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, low-latency

I have a critical thread that processes data in a tight loop. It is affinity bound and meant for high-performance processing. It does no dynamic allocations.

I have another thread that is running on a different core that does none critical work but however does do dynamic allocations. It is affinity bound also.

Will the presence of this other thread doing dynamic allocations affect my critical thread?

Comment: The different cores are likely to share cache, so the none critical thread can cause cache misses or even [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)). But so can any other process.

Comment: Good point. My guess is that dynamically allocated memory would have a bigger impact on the cache than if objects were on the stack.

Comment: Also, sometimes it is not obvious to predict when (and on which thread) the dynamic allocation actually happens. Might be worth double checking if the critical thread is actually free of dynamic allocation (e.g. string copy on write)

Comment: The two threads still share the same heap. Dynamic allocations lead to heap fragmentation, which slows the allocation/deallocation.

Comment: The one dynamically allocating has to lock the global lock that protects the heap when allocating, but if your critical thread isn't contending that lock it shouldn't be slowed down.

Comment: If your critical thread does not allocate memory I don't think the two would interfere at all. On some systems you might even get separate heap pools for each thread, such that allocating memory in parallel on two threads will only interfere at a few specific points in time (namely when a new pool of heap memory is required for a thread). This is just speculation though.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, yes.
Not only for indirect effect of memory layout and L3 trashing, but also an immediate effect once in a while.
When *malloc* is called it tries to reuse what was already allocated and freed, but sometimes has to extend the process memory space, and it does this by calling *mmap*, or *brk*.
I'm not 100% sure about *brk*, but *mmap* definitely invalidates the TLB so you should expect slower handling of page faults right after these calls.
If you're on Linux, or *BSD, you can try fiddle with the kernel code to not invalidate in all cases, but don't expect it to be simple.

Comment: The system call effects are one-off effects: Once the virtual memory space has reached is maximum size, there will be no more TLB flushes. Since processor affinity is used, there will also be no more significant L3 trashing than any other thread will create. As the OP states that the time critical thread does not allocate any memory, no direct latency is introduced via `malloc()` calls. But as always with performance, truth is only in measurement.